# How to customize ActionBar tabs positioning?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

How can I customize the actionbar tabs positioning, to do something similar to this?
[image: http://www.android-app-patterns.com/img/screens/52376bb9d8379.png]

I'm using this tabs, not a tab widget.

> actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: Use a normal `TabHost`.

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see what that app is doing. That is not action bar tabs. My guess is that it is a `ViewPager`'s indicator.